# Returning undefined with req.query.ID and multiple sql statements in a Node.js route

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am trying to display some information I have using a req.query.ID call. I think I understand why it is returning undefined, but I don't know if my presumptions are correct. I can get the desired output if I hard code the values into the query, but not when I use req.query.ID.

This is for a school assignment, so sql injections and vulnerabilities are exactly my highest concern right now.

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {


var sql = "Select * from UserInfo where UserEmail = '"+ req.body.UserEmailLogin +"'";
con.query(sql, function(error, results, fields){
  if(error){
    console.log(error);
  }

  console.log(results);
  res.redirect('profile?ID=' + results[0].UserID);
})
});


app.get('/profile', function(req, res){

  var sqlQuery = 'Select UserID, UserFirstName, UserLastName from UserInfo where UserID = ' + req.query.ID; +
  '  SELECT * FROM GroupCreate LEFT JOIN UserInfo ON UserInfo.UserID = GroupCreate.UserInfo_UserID LEFT JOIN GroupInfo ON GroupInfo.GroupID = GroupCreate.GroupInfo_GroupID Where UserInfo_UserID = ' + req.query.ID; +
  ' Select * from GroupInfo where GroupType = "Sports";'
  con.query(sqlQuery, function(error, results, fields){
    if(error) throw error;

    res.render('profile', {
      title: "Profile",
      results: results[0],
      results1: results[1],
      results2: results[2],
      Username: results[0].UserFirstName + " " + results[0].UserLastName
    });
    console.log(results[0]);
    console.log(results[1]);
    console.log(results[2]);
  });

});
```

The problem doesn't persist if I hard code the value "1" where both the req.query.ID is located in the app.get section.

The url parameter ends up looking like http://localhost:3000/profile?ID=1 but the results:results[1] and results:results:[2] return undefined.

Comment: Just an observation why do you have 3 SQL statements appended back to back in profile get handler?

Comment: I want to display a few different things from my database. It's all dummy data but it only works if I hard code in values instead of doing it dynamically. I'll have to update you on a few hours when I wake up. I am using the multiplestatements option in mysql

Answer (score 0):

If SQL injection is a concern of yours, then never construct an SQL query by appending values, instead pass values in parameter format. I am assuming you are using mysql package.

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?',[id], (err, results) => {
        // Do whatever you want to
    }
);
```

And I am guessing why your `res.redirect('profile?ID=' + results[0].UserID);` doesn't work is because value might not be URL safe(huge assumption from my side). Try this and reply to me if this doesn't work.

`res.redirect('profile?ID=' + encodeURIComponent(results[0].UserID));`

Refer [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)